# How to invert the color of a text layer with a sliding adjustment layer

Tags: after-effects

So I'm trying to recreate the effects used in this Envato video

https://videohive.net/item/sport-life-fast-dynamic-slideshow/19632953

This is what I have so far https://gfycat.com/RichAstonishingDalmatian

What I basically want to do is to have a single text layer (selected comp) but I want it to be white on the color footage and black once the pink overlays it. Essentially, I don't want to maintain multiple copies of the text animation (or any other layer). If I change it once in one place it has to be able to cascade to all other places.

As it stands now it stays white and I can't quite figure out how to keep the layer/comp usage to a minimum while still changing the color of the text with the pink overlay.

P.S. Yeah Mark is a crazy guy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the text only once inside one comp, but duplicate multiple copies of it in your main comp, so you will only need to create the text once.

Then set one of them to be inverted or whatever other colour setting you want.

Then make a layer that contains your moving mattes, and add a track matte to each of the text layers, pointing to your moving matte layer.

Mark does indeed look crazy :)